# vue3 routing nginx server page not found (404) when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx

I included this on nginx and routing still not working when refreshing page

nginx:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

route(vue):

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Access',
    component: () => import('@/views/Access'),
    meta: {
      guest: true
    }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```